# A question about a proof of $\mathsf{GCH}$ over a extender model $L[\mathcal{E}]$

Tags: solution-verification, set-theory

I am reading the proof of $\mathsf{GCH}$ over $L[\mathcal{E}]$ for a coherent sequence of $\sigma$-complete extenders $\mathcal{E}$ given by Mitchell (Theorem 3.24 of Mitchell's *Beginning Inner Model Theory*.) However, I am stuck on a detail of the proof. Let me iterate some parts of the proof and relevant notions for convenience.

A transitive model $M$ is a *coarse mouse* in $L[\mathcal{E}]$ with projectum $\rho$ if $$M\cong \mathcal{H}^{L_\tau[\mathcal{E}]}(\{\mathcal{E}\}\cup\rho\cup p)\prec L_\tau[\mathcal{E}]\models \mathsf{ZF^-}$$ for some finite set of parameter $p\in L_\tau[\mathcal{E}]$.

Mitchell claimed that it suffices to show that, for every coarse mice $M$ and $N$ in $L[\mathcal{E}]$ with the same projectum $\rho$, either $\mathcal{P}^M(\rho)\subseteq N$ or $\mathcal{P}^N(\rho)\subseteq M$ holds. Then he uses induction on $\rho$ to prove $L[\mathcal{E}]\models 2^\rho=\rho^+$.

The proof is divided into two cases: the first case is when $o^\mathcal{E}(\kappa)\le\rho$ for all $\kappa<\rho$ holds, which is not too hard to understand. The second case is if there is $\kappa<\rho$ such that $o^\mathcal{E}(\kappa)>\rho$. The proof goes as follows:

> Let $M=L_\alpha[\mathcal{F}]$ be a coarse $\rho$-mouse in $L[\mathcal{E}]$. Then $\mathcal{P}^{L[\mathcal{E}]}(\kappa)\subseteq M$: note that if $x\in\mathcal{P}^{L[\mathcal{E}]}(\kappa)$, then $x$ is definable from $\xi<\kappa^{+L[\mathcal{E}]}$ and $\mathcal{E}$ (by saying that $x$ is the $\alpha$th element under the canonical well-ordering.) The same formula with $\mathcal{F}$ and $\xi$ defines some $y$ over $M=L_\alpha[\mathcal{F}]$, and let $\pi:M\to L_\tau[\mathcal{E}]$ is the map induced by the transitive collapsing. Then $\pi(x)=x\in M$, since $\pi(y)=x$ and $x\subseteq \kappa$.
>
> Now take $\beta=o^\mathcal{F}(\kappa)$, then the extenders $\mathcal{F}(\kappa,\gamma)$ for $\gamma<\beta_\kappa$ are all extenders in $L[\mathcal{E}]$. **It follows from Lemma 3.19 that $\mathcal{F}(\kappa,\gamma)=\mathcal{E}(\kappa,\gamma)$ for all $\gamma<\beta$,** so $\mathcal{F}\upharpoonright (\kappa+1)=\mathcal{E}\upharpoonright (\kappa,\beta)$.
>
> For each two coarse $\rho$-mice $M$ and $N$ such that $\beta^M=\beta^N<\rho^{+L[\mathcal{E}]}$. The remaining argument goes as Mitchell stated in his proof.

My questions are the following:

1. Is my proof for $\mathcal{P}^{L[\mathcal{E}]}(\kappa)\subseteq M$ correct?
2. I have no idea how to prove the bolded statement (that is, $\mathcal{F}(\kappa,\gamma)=\mathcal{E}(\kappa,\gamma)$ for all $\gamma<\beta$.) Theorem 3.19 states the following fact:

> **Theorem.** Let $\mathcal{E}$ be a weakly coherent extender sequence and that $E$ be a $\sigma$-complete $(\kappa,\kappa+1+\beta)$-extender in $L[\mathcal{E}]$ such that $o^{i^E(\mathcal{E})}(\kappa)=\beta$. Then $E=\mathcal{E}(\kappa,\beta)$.

It is like that I have to relate $\mathcal{E}$ and $\mathcal{F}$ in some way, but I do not know how to start.